# How to escape parentheses in github markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have the following line on a markdown text file:

[Recursively] (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

When it's rendered the parser breaks the link by picking the first closing parenthesis instead of the second.

The link ends up as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science instead of
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)

How do I escape the first closing bracket?

I have tried using a backslash and using backticks but they don't work.

Comment: Your question is somewhat of a duplicate, though not necessarily exactly. Here is some more information that may be helpful to you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses

Comment: I found a detailed answer and insight of this issue [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

Answer (score 6):

I found a detailed answer and insight of this issue [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13501/links-to-urls-containing-parentheses)

Here is a snippet

`1. Bare             - http://example.com/test(1).html
2. Bare, encoded    - http://example.com/test%281%29.html
3. Delimited        - <http://example.com/test(1).html>
4. Hyperlink        - with <a href="http://example.com/test(1).html">parens</a>
5. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens][1]
6. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens at end][2]
7. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
8. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test(1))`

1. Bare             - http://example.com/test(1).html
2. Bare, encoded    - http://example.com/test%281%29.html
3. Delimited        - http://example.com/test(1).html
4. Hyperlink        - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
5. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
6. Markdown Link #1 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test_(test))
7. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens](http://example.com/test(1).html)
8. Markdown Link #2 - with [parens at end](http://example.com/test(1))